# Rename nested lists R

Tags: r, list, names

I am trying to organize my raw data for a series of statistics tests. I have created a large list with all raw data from different experiments, like as below.

```
E1 <- runif(60,0,1)
E2 <- runif(60,0,1)
E3 <- runif(60,0,1)
Data = list("E1"=E1, "E2"=E2, "E3"=E3)

Format.Data <- function(x){
  (dim(x) <- c(5,3,4))
  colnames(x) <- paste("Col", 1:3, sep="");  x
  rownames(x) <- paste("Rep", 1:5, sep="");  x
}
Raw.Data <- lapply(Data, Format.Data)
```

This will generate a list of nested lists `$E1` to `$E3` containing nested matrices `,,1` to `,,4` showing 5 experimental repetitions of 3 columns. I would like to change the names of these nested lists from `,,1` to `,,4` to, say, the names in the vectors below:

```
TreatmentsE1 <- c("Zero", "Two", "Four", "Eight")
TreatmentsE2 <- c("Zero", "0.25", "0.5", "One")
TreatmentsE3 <- c("Zero", "0.25", "0.5", "One")
```

I cannot seem to be able to do that. R keeps telling me that the length of `Raw.Data` of is 3, and the length of any nested `$E1` to `$E3` is 60. I want to rename the nested matrices, not the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to change the `dimnames` of the elements of the `list` with the 'TreatmentsE' values

```
Raw.Data1 <- Map(function(x,y) {dimnames(x)[[3]] <- y
                                x},
        Raw.Data, mget(paste0("TreatmentsE", 1:3)))
```

Comment: Perfect! It looks great now, many thanks! I am struggling to understand why accessing names of nested list parts is so complicated. I have found several discussions on parts of this issue, and this specific one was holding me back.